# Get extended information on Azure Advisor recommendations via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cli, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to use Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation command for automatic sending of emails to users, that appear in Advisor's alerts. Issue being, that Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation command does not show the actual description of the recommendation, like "Right-size or shutdown underutilized virtual machines" in the output. It only gives vague information like "ShortDescription: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Advisor.Cmdlets.Models.PsRecommendationBaseShortDescription" and RecommendationTypeID.
Azure CLI "az advisor recommendation list" command does provide the information under "shortDescription" value. Is there any way to get the same information using Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. `ShortDescription` is returned in the response as a [nested property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/queries-azureps?view=azps-5.5.0#select-nested-properties). You can access it as follows:

```
Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation | Select-Object RecommendationTypeId, @{Name="ShortDescription"; Expression={$_.ShortDescription.Problem}}
```

Include (select) other properties as needed.